# Facebook's Open Graph doesn't read meta tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I can't get Facebook's Open Graph to work on this link:

https://www.vitrinesonline.com.br/promocao/VE5Wpywz9M

It has all the tags necessary, still, Open Graph Debugger says it doesn't.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**[UPDATE]**

As luschn pointed out, I fixed the meta tags placement, scraped the url again and the debugger shows the same 3 errors:

> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
>
> Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid.

My SSL certificate is up to date and working properly. It's a free certificate, from Let's Encrypt. I wonder if that is the problem.

Comment: Your certificate chain is incomplete, https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.vitrinesonline.com.br Go research how to install the full chain on your server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is what the debugger says:

> Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will
>   cause browser warnings) or it is invalid.

Side note: you should put the meta tags before any JS or CSS files.

Comment: how about the ssl certificate? the placement was just a side note. if facebook does not recognize the certificate, you could file a bug.

Comment: Will look into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same problem, and the solution came from: http://rameerez.com/facebook-sharing-not-scraping-url-correctly-with-https-links/ and especially from the mentionned link: https://whatsmychaincert.com/.

I had to generate a chain file (provided by the site) and then add it to the configuration file of my domain on my server, by adding `SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/file.chain.crt`.

Then restart apache, re-debug on facebok and it was ok!

Comment: Yes, It turned out I had to generate another chain too. It is now working properly.

Comment: This worked perfectly after I added the correct chain file as described, thanks!